# Ugh! Another "what is it" puzzle? Seriously?

Tags: riddle

Super hard.

> I am only useful
>
> When I am full,
>
> Yet I am always
>
> Full of holes.

Comment: Isn't this a little too broad? How about giving some hints to narrow down the possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible you are a

> Sponge? [image: answer]

EDIT - Explanation:

> A sponge doesn't really work that well unless it's full of water. Also the spongy material itself is full of holes as seen in the picture.

Comment: How is that only useful when full?

Comment: @gnovice fullllllll....of water. Dry sponges aren't very helpful

Comment: @Sensoray: Actually, a dry sponge can soak up quite a bit of liquid. It's quite useful.

Comment: @gnovice That's true! I suppose they can be used in that way. I've never really used them to soak up spills though. I always used them for washing down things.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Can you explain why you think this is the answer? Answers without explanation are usually deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be a...

> watering can?
>  [image]

Comment: I don't think that's "**full** of holes". ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be

> A Colander
>  [image: A Colander]
>  A Colander is only used when you place something in it to sift or strain, and it is full of holes.

Comment: Good one, but the answer is above. Wow, so many answers.